# Unicode FontAwesome on Sass in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, sass

I was using fontawesome as an Icon, the fortawesome package is working well on React with their components. But I want to use the unicode and it only shows a Box (invalid) when I use the fontawesome unicode from their website. (I also using a Fontawesome Pro v5)

Comment: Does this solve the issue? `font-weight: 900;` https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946

Comment: Unfortunately no, I already saw that issue before I go here. I also try to play with different font weigths and font styles

Answer (score 0):

I already solve the problem, Tho I don't know if this is the better way to do it but since I use the fortawesome package I use this code

```
$fa-font-path: '../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/webfonts';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/solid.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/regular.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/scss/light.scss';
```